# Python requests.get() not showing all HTML

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I'm looking to scrape some information from [Easy Allies reviews](https://www.easyallies.com/#!/reviews) for a personal project using:

- Python3
- requests
- BS4 (BeautifulSoup)

I would like to scrape the names of the last games they have reviewed which is easy to find within the browser inspect tool, but doesn't exist within the source code of the page which is what is returned with this Python code:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

page = requests.get("http://www.easyallies.com/#!/reviews")
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, 'html.parser')

print(soup.prettify())
```

How do I access this data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Notice that when you open that url, it calls an endpoint `https://www.easyallies.com/api/review/get` that will fetch the reviews.

Take this code as an example, and parse the JSON result as you wish.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

data = { 'method': 'review', 'action': 'get', 'data[start]': 0, 'data[limit]': 10 }
reviews = requests.post("https://www.easyallies.com/api/review/get", data=data)

print (reviews.text)
```

Comment: Nice answer, I'll vote for it up since I did not followed the requests for the site. just inspected elements directly.

Answer (score 1):

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

browser = webdriver.Firefox()

url = 'https://www.easyallies.com/#!/reviews'
sada = browser.get(url)
time.sleep(3)
source = browser.page_source
soup = BeautifulSoup(source, 'html.parser')

for item in soup.findAll('div', attrs={'class': 'name'}):
    print(item.text)
```

[image]